# Работают не все actions (404)

Tags: yii2

Есть такой контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class StockController extends Controller{
    public function behaviors(){
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['*'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions(){
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        var_dump("index work");die();
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionGGList(){
        var_dump("list work");die();
        return $this->render('gglist');
    }
}
```

Экшен index работает как должен, а вот gglist выдает ошибку 404:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS

это стало происходить после работы GII

Comment: экшен `actionGGList` из вашего контроллера будет доступен по адресу:  `stock/g-g-list`, потому что все заглавные буквы после первой во вью превращаются в тире перед ними, вот тут можно почитать: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#creating-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Названия имен действий являются регистрозависимыми. Например, если у Вас есть метод **ActionIndex**, он не будет учтен как метод действия, таким образом, запрос к действию **index** приведет к выбросу исключению.

В Вашем случае действие содержит название **actionGGList**, в таком случае вам нужно обращаться по адресу **controllerName/g-g-list**.

Также следует учесть, что методы действий должны иметь область видимости public. Методы имеющие область видимости **private** или **protected** НЕ определяют методы встроенных действий.

Подробно тут: [Читать](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-controllers.md)